# CancelledError exception handler not triggering

Tags: python, python-3.x, task, python-asyncio

My exception handler for tasks being cancelled seems to trigger for simple cases, but not when using multiple tasks or `asyncio.gather`.

Sample code:

```py
import asyncio


async def sleep_func(statement, time, sabotage=False):
    print(f"Starting: {statement}")
    try:
        if sabotage:
            tasks = [
                asyncio.sleep(1000),
                asyncio.sleep(1000),
                asyncio.sleep(1000),
            ]
            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        await asyncio.sleep(time)
    except asyncio.CancelledError as e:
        print(f"cancelled {statement}! - {str(e)}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unhandled exception - {str(e)}")
    print(f"Ending: {statement}")


async def main():
    calls = [
        asyncio.ensure_future(sleep_func("eat", 3)),
        asyncio.ensure_future(sleep_func("pray", 8)),
        asyncio.ensure_future(sleep_func("love", 10, sabotage=True)),
    ]
    print("starting!")
    finished, unfinished = await asyncio.wait(calls, timeout=6)
    for task in unfinished:
        task.cancel("This message should be shown when task is cancelled")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I have three tasks in my main function:

```py
[
    asyncio.ensure_future(sleep_func("eat", 3)),
    asyncio.ensure_future(sleep_func("pray", 8)),
    asyncio.ensure_future(sleep_func("love", 10, sabotage=True)),
]
```

Expected:

- My first task is not cancelled (this works)
- My second task is cancelled and prints the message in the
  `CancelledError` handler correctly (this works)
- My second task is cancelled and prints the message in the
  `CancelledError` handler correctly (this does NOT work)

Why is the `CancelledError` handler not triggering for the last task, which uses `asyncio.gather` and has a bunch of sub-tasks?

Output:

```
starting!
Starting: eat
Starting: pray
Starting: love
Ending: eat
cancelled pray! - This message should be shown when task is cancelled
Ending: pray
```

Expected output:

```
starting!
Starting: eat
Starting: pray
Starting: love
Ending: eat
cancelled pray! - This message should be shown when task is cancelled
Ending: pray
cancelled love! - This message should be shown when task is cancelled
Ending: love
```

Comment: One unrelated comment: You should also reraise any asyncio.CancelledError. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-cancellation):  "It is recommended that coroutines use try/finally blocks to robustly perform clean-up logic. In case asyncio.CancelledError is explicitly caught, it should generally be propagated when clean-up is complete."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are not seeing the cancellation of the `love` task is that you are **not awaiting it**.

By the time you get to the end of your cancellation `for`-loop, the tasks have **not been cancelled**, they are just **cancelling**, i.e. in the process of being cancelled.

Calling the [`Task.cancel`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel) method does not immediately cancel the task. To quote the docs (with my own emphasis), it

> arranges for a `CancelledError` exception to be thrown into the wrapped coroutine **on the next cycle of the event loop**.

To allow the next event loop cycle to actually commence, you need an `await` expression. That will allow a context switch to one of the couroutines to happen and the `CancelledError` to actually be raised there.

But your `main` coroutine ends without another `await`, thus without the possibility of a context switch by the event loop. This is why in the example code snippet under the `Task.cancel` documentation, the tasks that is to be cancelled is **awaited** at the end.

Thus, the simplest way to get your desired output would be to simply add `await task` right below `task.cancel(...)` in your `for`-loop:

```py
...

async def main():
    calls = [
        asyncio.ensure_future(sleep_func("eat", 3)),
        asyncio.ensure_future(sleep_func("pray", 8)),
        asyncio.ensure_future(sleep_func("love", 10, sabotage=True)),
    ]
    print("starting!")
    finished, unfinished = await asyncio.wait(calls, timeout=6)
    for task in unfinished:
        task.cancel("This message should be shown when task is cancelled")
        await task  # <---
```

---

As to why *one* of the two tasks that you called `cancel` on actually managed to send the `CancelledError` to its coroutine, I don't know the internals of the loop's `run_until_complete` method well enough, but suspect that it does allow for another context switch inside it before returning. But I would speculate that this is just an implementation detail and not reliable at all (as demonstrated by your example), even less so, when the number of cancelled tasks increases.

---

As an aside, you should probably not be using the `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()` pattern anymore due to its deprecation. The canonical way of running your asynchronous `main` function is via [`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-runner.html#asyncio.run).

Also, when you have multiple tasks to be cancelled, the pattern is usually to [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) them after requesting cancellation.

Lastly, as mentioned in a comment, it is best practice to re-raise a caught `CancelledError` in a coroutine. You can then avoid it "further up the chain" in your `main` function by simply passing `return_exceptions=True` to `asyncio.gather` for the unfinished cancelled tasks.

So the changes I would suggest to your example code would look as follows:

```py
import asyncio

async def sleep_func(statement, time, sabotage=False):
    print(f"Starting: {statement}")
    try:
        if sabotage:
            tasks = [
                asyncio.sleep(1000),
                asyncio.sleep(1000),
                asyncio.sleep(1000),
            ]
            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        await asyncio.sleep(time)
    except asyncio.CancelledError as e:
        print(f"cancelled {statement}! - {str(e)}")
        raise e  # <---
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unhandled exception - {str(e)}")
    finally:  # <---
        print(f"Ending: {statement}")

async def main():
    calls = [
        asyncio.ensure_future(sleep_func("eat", 3)),
        asyncio.ensure_future(sleep_func("pray", 8)),
        asyncio.ensure_future(sleep_func("love", 10, sabotage=True)),
    ]
    print("starting!")
    finished, unfinished = await asyncio.wait(calls, timeout=6)
    for task in unfinished:
        task.cancel("This message should be shown when task is cancelled")
    await asyncio.gather(*unfinished, return_exceptions=True)  # <---

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())  # <---
```

Output:

```
starting!
Starting: eat
Starting: pray
Starting: love
Ending: eat
cancelled pray! - This message should be shown when task is cancelled
Ending: pray
cancelled love! - This message should be shown when task is cancelled
Ending: love
```

---

**PS**: Starting with Python `3.11` we have the [`asyncio.TaskGroup`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-groups) class that provides a convenient context manager for such cases. Utilizing that we could write the `main` function like this:

```py
...

async def main():
    print("starting!")
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        tasks = [
            tg.create_task(sleep_func("eat", 3)),
            tg.create_task(sleep_func("pray", 8)),
            tg.create_task(sleep_func("love", 10, sabotage=True)),
        ]
        finished, unfinished = await asyncio.wait(tasks, timeout=6)
        for task in unfinished:
            task.cancel("This message should be shown when task is cancelled")
```

Notice how **do not** need to await the tasks ourselves here because

> all tasks are awaited when the context manager exits.

And we also don't need to worry about the propagated `CancelledError` because that will not "leak" out of the task group context.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

The problem here seems to be that there is no time for the gathered tasks to actually get through with the cancellation and throw the CancellationError to the wrapping `try_except_sleeper`

`cancel` only requests the cancellation and returns immediately [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel)

## Solution

Add `await asyncio.wait(unfinished, timeout=1)` to the last line of your `main` function. That way the coroutines will have enough time to process the cancelation request and the output will be:

```
starting!
Starting: eat
Starting: pray
Starting: love
Ending: eat
cancelled pray! - This message should be shown when task is cancelled
cancelled love! -
```

As a side note: You see the cancellation message has not been passed to the wrapper - I don't know why that is, might be a bug.

Comment: While this _might_ work with those 3 tasks, this is a highly unreliable way to ensure the tasks will actually be done. Explicitly `await`ing them should be preferred, either by just using `await task` on each, by using `asyncio.gather` on all or (more modern) just using a [`TaskGroup`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.TaskGroup) to begin with.